# Class not found when successfully included

Tags: php

I get this fatal error for class not being found:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'HomeController' not found

But the file is included.

```
require_once self::CONTROLLERS_PATH . $this->controller . '.php';
var_dump(file_exists(self::CONTROLLERS_PATH . $this->controller . '.php'));
new $this->controller;
```

I debugged it by var_dumping `file_exists` which returns true. I checked the namespaces and everything looks good. If I var dump `$this->controller`, its value is as intended - `string(14) "HomeController"`. If I hard code it like `new HomeController();`, the class is initialized. Why is it not working from the variable, though? You can see my code below. This is my file structure:

[image]

App.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Core;

class App
{
    protected $controller = 'HomeController';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    const CONTROLLERS_PATH = '../App/Controllers/';

    public function __construct ()
    {
        $url = $this->parseUrl();

        if(file_exists(self::CONTROLLERS_PATH . ucfirst($url[0]) . '.php'))
        {
            $this->controller = ucfirst($url[0]); //Update $this->controller value
            unset($url[0]);
            echo 'file exists';
        }
        require_once self::CONTROLLERS_PATH . $this->controller . '.php';
        var_dump(file_exists(self::CONTROLLERS_PATH . $this->controller . '.php'));
        var_dump($this->controller);
        new $this->controller;

        if(isset($url[1]))
        {
            if(method_exists($this->controller, $url[1]))
            {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
                echo 'method exists';
            }
        }

        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url): [];
        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
        var_dump($url);
    }

    public function parseUrl()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['url']))
        {
            return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
}
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

    class HomeController
    {
        public function index()
        {
            echo 'asd';
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it namespaced maybe? (even if it's the same namespace as this script)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Do you have on top of this script (and/or) the HomeController.php something like `namespace App\Controller`

Comment: Yes I do. I added links to pastebin in my post.

Comment: I strongly suggest you just use composers autoloading instead of wiring up your own solution

Comment: you'll have to include the namespace if you call a class via variable like so: `new \App\Controllers\$this->controller;`

Comment: I do have composer and the `autoload.php` file is included.

Comment: @Jeff How exactly can I do this? The example you provided throws a syntax error. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier`

Comment: ah, sorry, forgot you have to put it all into a var first: `$className = "\\App\\Controllers\\".$this->controller;` then `new $className;`

Comment: Ok, now it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I'll write it as an answer then

Comment: For future reference, you need to paste your code into the actual question instead of linking to third party sites. If those links change, this question will be useless for future visitors.

Comment: Ok. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When instantiating a class via a variable name you always have to include the whole namespace. And this has to be stored as a string first.
An example:

```
namespace Api;

Class test {

    public function __construct() {
        echo "test";
    }
}

$className = 'test';
$classNameNamespaced = "\\Api\\".$className;

$a = new $classNameNamespaced;  // echoes "test"
```

in your case:

```
$className = "\\App\\Controllers\\".$this->controller;
new $className;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the code is in a namespace, `new $this->controller` is different than `new HomeController` even if the value of `$this->controller` is `HomeController`.

The expression `new HomeController` is evaluated at the compile time and, because of the namespace, it is expanded to `new \App\Controllers\HomeController` (rule #6 on the [Name resolution rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)). The interpreter needs the fully qualified class name in order to find it.

The expression `new $this->controller` is evaluated during runtime and it leads to `new HomeController` which is the same as `new \HomeController`. There isn't any class `HomeController` defined in the root namespace, hence the error you get.

You can make it easily work by building the full class name into a string:

```
$class = 'App\\Controllers\\'.$this->controller;
new $class;
```

Find more examples in the documentation page ["Namespaces and dynamic language features"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php).

But the best way to load classes is to use the [autoloader generated by Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Comment: needn't there to be a `\\` at the start of the namespace? Because we are already in a namespace..

Comment: The namespaces exist only in the code. During compilation all object names are expanded to fully qualified names. During runtime there are no namespaces and the names are not expanded. Any name you have as string in a variable is treated as a fully qualified name, it doesn't matter if it starts with a backslash or not. Take a look at example #2 on the [Namespaces and dynamic language features](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) documentation page.